# How to replace all buffer content by some string?

Tags: vimscript

For example, if I run some external program (formatter) from vim and write result of it to some variable:

```
let result=system("some_program", getline(1, "$"))
" do something with result
```

How I can replace all current buffer content by the `result`?

PS result must be same as `%!some_program`, but I can not use this. If program failed it return not `0` code and error message with line and column of error, I use this message for create `cbuffer`. So I need write result of program to variable, check return code and handle it.

Comment: *PS result must be same as %!`some_program`.* Why not just use `%!some_program` then? Update your question to indicate why using that is not an option...

Comment: @filbranden update question

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
silent let result=systemlist("some_program", getline(1, "$"))
" do something with result
" cleanup buffer
normal! gg_dG
call setline(1, result)
```

Or this:

```
silent let result=system("some_program", getline(1, "$"))
" do something with result
" cleanup buffer
:%delete _
call setline(1, split(result, '\n'))
```

If you want specific buffer to be replaced, use `setbufline` and adjust "cleanup buffer" command.

Comment: Your delete command can be written as `:%delete _`, though I'm not sure it's necessary with `setline`

Comment: There's also `deletebufline()`, so you could use `call deletebufline('.', 1, '$')` to delete everything. @D.BenKnoble just using `setline()` directly won't work if `result` has fewer lines than the original buffer contents.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, indeed `:%delete _` is better here. Thx!